# Passing multiple arguments through the URL in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, get, arguments

In my home page, I have a form with three dropdown boxes. Upon clicking on the submit button, I send the form arguments to the server through a GET request and then redirect to a search-results.php page to show the results of a search based on the three arguments. I need to have the arguments in the URL in case a user wants to reproduce the search just by copying and pasting the URL. My problem is that when the search-results page loads, only the first argument is shown in the URL and when I reload the page, only that argument can be retrieved in the server. I have pretty permalinks enabled but disabling it didn't make any difference.

Here's the code for my form:

```
<form action="{{ esc_url( admin_url( 'admin-post.php' )) }}" method="GET">
  <input name="action" type="hidden" value="form_response">
  <select name="param1">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
  </select> 
  <select name="param2">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
  </select> 
  <select name="param3">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
  </select> 
  <button type="submit" name="search_button">Search</button>
</form>
```

Then, on the server, I receive the GET request with all the arguments, process the search and then redirect to the search-results page:

```
$url = add_query_arg(array(
  'param1' => $_GET['param1'],
  'param2' => $_GET['param2'],
  'param3' => $_GET['param3'],
), get_permalink(get_page_by_path('search-results')));  

if(wp_redirect($url)) {
  exit;
}
```

I tell Wordpress to accept the arguments by adding the following filter:

```
add_filter('query_vars', function($vars) {
  $vars[] = "param1";
  $vars[] = "param2";
  $vars[] = "param3";
  return $vars;
});
```

When the search-results page loads with the correct data, the URL is:

```
www.mysite.com/search-results/?param1=1
```

param2 and param3 simply disappear. Copying and pasting this URL will load the page without the arguments.

I'm trying to find a workaround for this issue. Does anyone have any ideas? Am I doing anything wrong?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was missing. I also needed to add a rewrite rule to translate the URL with the GET arguments into what I wanted:

```
/**
 * Add a rewrite rule to accept GET arguments on the search results page
 */
add_filter('init', function() {
  add_rewrite_rule(
    // The resulting URL with regex to match the incoming arguments
    'search/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?',
    // The expected URL
    'index.php?pagename=search-results&param1=$matches[1]&param2=$matches[2]&param3=$matches[3]',
    // This is a rather specific URL, so we add it to the top of the list
    // Otherwise, the "catch-all" rules at the bottom (for pages and attachments) will "win"
    'top' );
});
```

In other words, when Wordpress receives a GET request for the page 'search-results' containing param1=1, param2=2 and param3=3, it translates it into the following URL:

```
www.mysite.com/search-results/1/2/3/
```